# R match changes order

Tags: r, match

I have a vector (A, say column names of A bigger matrix) and a matrix(B).

A = q,w,e,r,t

B =

```
q 1 
y 2
w 3
e 4
u 5
t 6
r 7
```

I match A with B's first column

matchAB =

```
      q 1
      w 3
      i 4
      e 5 
      t 6
      r 7
```

I only need the second column. and use it with A. If you see the order is not the same. where a = q,w,e,r,t. matchAB, becomes, q,w,e,t,r. I don't want to do alphabetical sorting on A. I want matchAB to have the same order as A. 
Any help ?

Thanks !

As asked by mnel:

> dput(a)

```
a =c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t")
```

> dput(b)

```
b <- structure(c("q", "1", "y", "2", "w", "3", "i", "4", "e", "5",
    "t", "6", "r", "7"), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("bi","bb"), NULL))


ind=which(match(b[1,],a) != 0)

> b[,ind]=

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

bi "q"  "w"  "e"  "t"  "r"

bb "1"  "3"  "5"  "6"  "7"
```

So, the output that I want is,

```
b[,ind]=

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

bi "q"  "w"  "e"  "r"  "t"

bb "1"  "3"  "5"  "7"  "6"
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by posting the `dput(A)` and `dput(B)`, and the code you used for matching. Is `B` really a matrix or a data.frame?

Comment: @Arshi it's probably best to add the data back in your original question.

Comment: Thanks Tyler ! Thanks mnel for dput, I am new to R and didn't know about it.

Comment: It's not doing alphabetical matching.  It matches the order of your original data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the order of the arguments needs to be the opposite of what you first think it should be:

```
> a = c('q','w','e','r','t'); b[, match(a,b[1,])]
#-------
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
bi "q"  "w"  "e"  "r"  "t" 
bb "1"  "3"  "5"  "7"  "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post a question it is very helpful to use `dput` as mnel has suggested.

You question is really about indexing.  First I'll show how I'd do it and then break it down:

**Your data recreated (please use 1dput` from now on):**

```
B <- read.table(text="q 1 
y 2
w 3
e 4
u 5
t 6
r 7", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

A <- c('q','w','e','r','t')
```

**How I'd do it:**

```
data.frame(A=A, B=B[B[, 1] %in% A, 2])
```

**Breaking it down:** 
Notice I set the column above as a factor?  This should retain your order. 
First the `%in%` operator matches the elements in column 1 of B with A and
as a factor the order is honored:

```
B[, 1] %in% A
# >     B[, 1] %in% A
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Then I use this logical vector inside of a new index of B and select only column 2

```
B[B[, 1] %in% A, 2]
# [1] 1 3 4 6 7
```